# Only top-level class methods can be declared static

Tags: apex, compile-error

I'm really hoping someone can help me here. I have tried numerous times with this code but still get the same error. I have even used other code I have found on-line that apparently 'works', but with the same error.

Below is an example of someone else's code (not mine) that they say works, but unfortunately not for me. Why is it that I am still getting the same error even with this?

```
public class AccountHandler {
    public static Account insertNewAccount(string AcctName)        
    {

        try{
        Account acct=new Account(Name=AcctName);
        insert acct;
        return acct;
         }
        catch (DMLException e)
        {
            System.debug('A DML exception has occurred: ' +
                         e.getMessage());
          return (NULL);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: seems u hv created AccountHandler as a sub class of another class. if u move that into a separate class it shd start working.

Comment: i'd be surprised if you got that error for that situation, but you are `return`  twice, which you can't do in apex.  I should be making this an answer but I don't know if this solution, I just know it would cause a problem by having two returns

Comment: @EricSSH - you can have multiple returns depending on the circumstances. The first return is if everything goes well, the second is if there is an error. In fact, if you do not add the return in the catch block or at the end of the method the compiler will throw the non void method must return xxx error

Comment: I just tried to save it with 2 returns, and it failed can you pseudo something for me to compile?

Comment: MavensMate wouldn't let me save with two returns, Developer console did I believe you now @Eric

Comment: Sure: public class myExample{

    public static string doIt(Boolean optionOne){
    
        if(optionOne)
            return 'First';
        else
            return 'Second';
    
    }


}

Comment: @VamsiKrishna - Please add that as an answer as I believe it is the correct one. An inner class cannot have a static method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credit goes to @Vamsi and if he posts I will delete (If I miss it someone please comment on this answer @me)....

An Inner class cannot have a static method. You must refactor the inner class to its own class.

This fails to compile throwing the error the OP is experiencing:

```
public class myExample{

    public static string doIt(Boolean optionOne){

        if(optionOne)
            return 'First';
        else
            return 'Second';

    }

    public class exampleTwo{

        public static string testIt(){
            return 'A';
        }

    }


}
```

However if you move the inner class `exampleTwo` to is own main class it will compile just fine

```
public class myExample{

    public static string doIt(Boolean optionOne){

        if(optionOne)
            return 'First';
        else
            return 'Second';

    }
}
```

Own class

```
    public class exampleTwo{

        public static string testIt(){
            return 'A';
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi Vamsi, thanks for the response and I'm sure you are correct. However, I have tried to use your exampleTwo as-is (simply copied and pasted) and still get exactly the same error.  Any ideas on why this could be?

Comment: @Darren - Then you are doing something wrong because a copy and paste of exampleTwo directly from above to a new Apex Class saves just fine.

Comment: Thanks @Eric .. I can post it as an answer but can't detail it like what you have done.. so happy to leave this with you.. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @Eric, I suspected as much because nearly everything I do doesn't seem to work. Not just on this challenge either, it is really frustrating doing this remotely. If it is not the code, I wonder what is the issue. Is it a browser issue, some setting hidden away on the Developer Console... ?

Comment: Hard to say. In SF, goto setup->Develop->Apex Classes, Click New, paste the exampleTwo class code and click save. You should have no issues.

Comment: Hi @Eric, THANKS SO MUCH! I've been using an Anonymous Window via the Developer Console and it kept throwing the error; but navigating the way you suggested allows the code to save, and the challenge is accepted and passed! I don't know what the difference is but it is worth knowing that it wasn't the code in any way.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, all of my classes were static so when I removed the keyword static it worked.

Before `public static void show_data(String start_date, String end_date) {...}`

After `public void show_data(String start_date, String end_date) {...}`

Comment: You meant "methods" here instead of "classes" (because your examples are methods, and classes cannot be static). I've downvoted this because you haven't explained _why_ this works (and under which circumstances an error will occur). This is mostly covered by Eric's answer from ~7 years ago. Inner classes cannot have static variables or methods. Additionally, anonymous apex is basically an "inner class" (not _entirely_ accurate, but close enough), which is why anon apex cannot have static variables/methods.

Comment: Hello @DerekF, thank you for your feedback. I post this answer to help others, if you or anyone want to know the details he can ask through a comment or can search dig down according to his need. From my point of view, I can downvote only if the solution doesn't work or it's not relevant at all. And I found Eric 's situation was different that's why I made this post. However, thank you.