# Compile Error: Line: 3, Column: 30 Only top-level class methods can be declared static

Tags: apex, compile-error

I get this error whenever I run the below code:

> Error - Only top-level class methods can be declared static

Code

```
public class ContactSearch 
{
    public static List<Contact> searchForContacts(String lastName, String mailCode)
    {
       return [SELECT Id, Name, LastName, MailingPostalCode 
               FROM Contact 
               WHERE LastName = :lastName AND MailingPostalCode = :mailCode];

    } 
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? I can't find the issue. I ran the accounts code the same way and it worked so I am confused with this error message.

(I tried to look for the answer in previous posts, but none applied to my case, therefore I am posing this new question.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Only top-level class methods can be declared static](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/135865/2995)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're declaring an inner class, all of its methods must be stateful:

```
public class TopLevel
{
    public class InnerClass
    {
        public List<Contact> search_WillCompile()
        {
            // this method declaration is valid
            // implementation details ommitted
        }
        public static List<Contact> search_WillNotCompile()
        {
            // this method declaration is invalid
        }
    }
}
```

That's in contrast to methods on a top level class, whose method declarations will compile either way:

```
public class TopLevel
{
    public static void staticMethod() { }
    public void statefulMethod() { }
}
```

If you're working within an `Execute Anonymous` window, all declared classes are virtual inner classes.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, that cleared everything out! This might be a very silly question, but do you know how can I run the code without using the Debug> Execute Anonymous?

Comment: @Ka_programmer Depends on what you're trying to accomplish, how regularly you intend to use it, and what sort of interface you're going for. You could hook it up to a `Visualforce Page` for a GUI, plug it into `ApexRest` or a `webservice` to create an API, and a variety of other scenarios.