# Error while trying to use Apex to update a record by Concatenating a third field from input in two other field

Tags: apex, developer

I wrote a piece of code to Concatenate certain words but I'm having issues with the code itself. Basically what I'm trying to do is Concatenate a field with "ABC" n times where n = number in another field.

```
public class AgeCounter {

public static void fillAgeCounter(List<CustomObject__c> records) {
    for(CustomObject__c record : records) {
        record.Age_Counter__c = 'ABC';
        for(Integer i = 1; i < record.ABC__c; i++) {
            record.Age_Counter__c = record.Age_Counter__c + ';' + 'ABC';
        }
        for(Integer i = 1; i < record.XYZ__c; i++) {
            record.Age_Counter__c = record.Age_Counter__c + ';' + 'XYZ';
        }
    }
    update records;
}}
```

This gives me the error: *Line: 3, Column: 24 static can only be used on methods of a top level type*

Removing static runs the code but no records are updated in the Custom object.

EX: Custom field ABC = 4 and Custom field XYZ = 2

Expected output after running this class: Field Age Counter gets updated as ABC;ABC;ABC;ABC;XYZ;XYZ

Comment: is AgeCounter an inner class? that would be why the static method can't be used. You'll need `new AgeCounter().fillAgeCounter(myrecords);` to invoke an inner class method

Comment: @cropredy no it's not an inner class. I'm running the code as is in the Execute anon window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is trying to execute your code inside of Execute Anonymous

Here's a simple example

```
class MyClass {
  static void myMethod() {}
}
```

when pasted into Execute Anonymous in Developer Console or (in your IDE), it fails with `static can only be used on methods of a top level type`.

- `MyClass` is actually an inner class to a synthetically-generated top level class.
- From this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/166069/2602) ...

> Note `If you're working within an Execute Anonymous window, all declared classes are virtual inner classes.`

Thought experiment: Imagine if you just entered into the Developer Console:

```
Integer i = 0;
```

and clicked Run. This works.  But, by itself in a file, this won't execute because it is not valid Apex. Statements need to be inside of methods or initializers.  But if wrapped inside of a class by the tooling, it can execute via the anonymous apex tooling.

To test your code in anonymous apex, paste this:

```
    CustomObject__c[] records = [SELECT .... FROM CustomObject__c ...];
    for(CustomObject__c record : records) {
        record.Age_Counter__c = 'ABC';
        for(Integer i = 1; i < record.ABC__c; i++) {
            record.Age_Counter__c = record.Age_Counter__c + ';' + 'ABC';
        }
        for(Integer i = 1; i < record.XYZ__c; i++) {
            record.Age_Counter__c = record.Age_Counter__c + ';' + 'XYZ';
        }
    }
    update records;
```

Comment: pasting the above code results in the error: Loop must iterate over collection.

Isn't it already going over the collection of records pulled from the Custom Object?

Comment: my bad - a typo -- fixed

Comment: Thanks it works. Also I forgot to add the records in the list. That's why it wouldn't iterate over them.

Changed `CustomObject__c[] records = [SELECT .... FROM CustomObject__c ...];`
To
`List<CustomObject__c[]> records = [SELECT .... FROM CustomObject__c ...];`

Comment: xxx[] is the same as List<XXX>; I'm glad this works and apologies again for the typo. As a service to the Community, you should mark the answer as accepted (check mark) if you're satisfied